# How to handle error stemming from cassandra-rackdc.properties file when using Ec2MultiRegionSnitch?

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra

I decided to use Amazon Web Services and Cassandra to run my web app, and now I'm configuring Cassandra for my production for the first time.

I've done all the configurations that I think nessasary such as setting endpoint_snitch to Ec2MultiRegionSnitch which can propagate to different regions, etc.

Problem is, after I set up `dc=us-east`, `rack=1`, and `dc_suffix=_Virginia_1` in cassandra-rackdc.properties file, I ran `bin/cassandra` to put the configuration in effect, but I got an error saying:

```
ERROR 12:41:13 Cannot start node if snitch's data center (us-east_Virginia_1) differs from previous data center (datacenter1). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.
```

It seems like adding

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true"
```

to the cassandra-env.sh is the solution, but it's suggested you add this only for your dev system, which isn't the case for me since I'm doing this for production.

Does anyone know how to handle this for my production server?

Answer (score 1):

It turned out that I can add `JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true"` to cassandra-env.sh for my production server as well. It just requires some downtime for my cluster to restart my datacenter.